# How can I get to the 'New issue' page on GitHub without clicking the Issues tab?

Tags: git, github

Is there a keyboard shortcut available to do this? I'm asking because 1) I go to the main page of the repo out of habit, and 2) I tend to get distracted looking at another issue, and forget what the original problem was.

Comment: Is pressing `gi` and then immediately pressing `c` not good enough?

Comment: @SoZettaSho That's fine, I just didn't know that. I did a Google search for "github new issues shortcut" and nothing came up in bold for [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/), so I didn't realize there was still a way to do it using the shortcuts listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `gi` and then `c` (*Go to Issues*, *Create*). See https://help.github.com/articles/using-keyboard-shortcuts/ for an exhaustive list.